Movie where wounded man drives car into house at night - fairly new
I remember a movie where a man is sitting in his house at night when suddenly a car slams through the wall, and the driver gets out and is wounded and tells the owner of the house to take something from him and keep it safe, and then dies. They were friends, and I believe the guy that dies did some kind of hitman/spy work. However, I don't remember what the object was. 
It's a fairly new movie, I would say from mid 2000s on. I just was watching John Wick 2 and was reminded of it because the cinematography and color timing was similar. It was definitely in the English language. I would say either Britain or America would be the country of release. 

Transporter 3 (2008)


At night, the Audi crashes into Frank's home, with a wounded transporter, Malcolm Melville, whom Frank had referred when he declined a previous job. As paramedics take away Malcolm, Frank discovers a woman in the back seat of the Audi who warns him not to take her from the car - she shows him a metal bracelet she and Malcolm have been wearing. Frank rushes outside, but the ambulance explodes, killing Malcolm. Frank is then knocked out by one of Johnson's henchmen.
Johnson places an explosive bracelet on Frank, forcing him to take a package and the woman, Valentina, to Budapest.
Wikipedia




